# Variable from user input BATCH

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm making a quick program just for fun in Batch coding.

I need to set a variable from the user's input, but I don't know how.
So far, I've made a "command" that you use to specify your name.

```
@echo OFF
title Name pl0x
color 0a
:start
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT= %=%
IF "%INPUT%"=="/mynameis name" (
goto :init
) ELSE (
goto :start
)
:init
REM I would echo the name like "hello, %NAME%!"
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I need it in the format of a command, like the user would write: 
`/mynameis Door Knob`
and not
`Enter your name:`

Answer (score 6):

When you use Set /P you are assigning a variable name to the received user prompt, the variable name wich you are using in this case is "INPUT".

Just use the same VarName ("INPUT") to print the variable here:

```
:init
REM I would echo the name like "hello, %NAME%!"
Echo Name: %INPUT%
Pause
```

Example:

```
@echo OFF
title Name pl0x
color 0a

:start
set /P "Name="
REM IF /I "%Name%" EQU "/mynameis name" (goto :init) ELSE (goto :start)


:init
Echo Hello, %Name% !
Pause&Exit
```

Output:

```
Write your name >> Elektro
Hello, Elektro !
```

> UPDATE:

```
@echo OFF

If /I %~1 EQU "/mynameis" (Set "Name=%~2") ELSE (Exit /B 1)

Echo Hello, %~2
Pause&Exit
```

Syntax:

```
Script.bat /mynameis {name}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you need, please specify it.

Comment: Like if I were to do /mynameis Door Knob. I tell the program my name with a command.

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on, could you explain to me?

Comment: I can't seem to make it work in the file... Could you show me the whole code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28921/discussion-between-door-knob-and-elektro-hacker)